# bash, grep, export, perl,ENV and if statements

Tags: bash, perl

I have this grep statements in bash script like

```
HDD3_block=$(grep -i $username block_access.db -s | awk -F ":" '{print $3}')
```

and I if use echo $HDD3_block I get 10 20 30 so I used

```
export HDD3_block
```

so I can used this variable in Perl

```
my $var4 = $ENV{"HDD3_block"};
```

I know I'm getting 10 20 30 because I used print "$var4\n"; but that not what I want I'm trying to run 10 20 30 through if statements in perl. Like

```
print "var result                   comments\n";
if ($var4 > 20){
print "$var4                        this is more than 20\n";
}elsif ($var < 20){
print "$var4                        this is less than 20\n";
}
```

but I am getting an error saying 10\n20\n30 isn't numeric so I'm guessing its getting all that value at once. Is there a way to separate 10 20 30 so the numbers goes through if statement one number at a time like 10 goes through if statement and it goes back get 20 and goes through if statement and it goes back gets 30 and goes through if statements. or is there another way of doing it.

Comment: not sure how to use that but I will Google it and try it out thanks for the tip :)

Comment: `split` is the Perl function to use. `perldoc -f split` is the command that will tell you how to use it.

Comment: yhea I managed to figure it out thanks now I have to implement while loop on it I think

Answer (score 0):

Ok so far I got this done

in perl I did

```
my $var5 = split(//,$var4);
```

but it doesn't go back for second number so I think I have to use while loop ahh...... my worst nightmare if I got anything I will update this answer.

no scrap this it not working at all when I print it I get 8. I will post further updates if I find anything

update 1

```
my @list  = split / /,$var4;
print "@list";
```

still not perfect because nothing happens in if statement

update 2

```
my $var4 = "10 20 30"; #I have pre defined the value for time sake other wise this value will come from bash script.

for my $var (split / /, $var4)
{
if ($var > 20)
{
print "over 20\n";
}
elsif ($var < 20)
{
print "less than 20\n";
}
}
```

completed!

Comment: If you want a list, you need to use one; `my @list = split /\n/, $var4;`.  You asked for a single value, so that's what you got.  When you assigned an array (the output from `split`) to a scalar, you get the number of elements in the array (hence 8, since you split on the empty string; that's the number of characters in "10 20 30").

Comment: Yeah; that's because you used `//` rather than `/\n/` or `/\s/` or `/ /` or some other variant splitting regex.  Don't split using `$_` unless you know a lot about Perl — sufficient that you'd not be asking this question.

Comment: ahhhh thank you now I get 10 20 30 now let me see if it works with if statement

Comment: it seems nothing happens when it goes through if statement its shows no error and it doesn't print anything

Comment: You will need a loop to iterate over the list elements one at a time.  `for my $var (split / /, $var4) { if ($var > 20) { print ...; } elsif ($var < 20) { print ...; } }`.  Note the `elsif` keyword.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler's comment contains valid _Perl_ code, it sounds like you tried it in the _shell_ by mistake.

Comment: I have updated my answer I have done exactly the way you said it

Comment: Your update doesn't contain the keyword `for` which my suggested iterative code does contain.

Comment: ahhh i give up now nothing happens it shows no error but again no print message.

Comment: You've lost the newlines in your print statements.  I got `less than 20over 20` printed and then my prompt when I run your final fragment, which is what you should get from your code.

Comment: yep that too and i had other code that was causing the issue now its fixed thank you